# Trying to print a 2d Array in a sudoku Style

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, printing, sudoku

So I'm trying to do a method show() for a Sudoku class. which uses a (9x9)2d array. this method show print the array in Sudoku style but I'm not sure how to implement it . I would really appreciate some help.

I'v already tried some "for loops" but as I said I don't really know how to separate the array in 3x3 squares. I'v included a small part of the code.

public void show()

```
{ 
    for(int[]row : values)
    {
        for(int value : row)
        {
            System.out.print(value);
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

the output that I need, may be something like this

0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0

0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0

0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0

---

0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0

0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0

0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0

---

0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0

0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0

0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0

current output:

0   0   0   8   5   9   3   0   0
5   0   4   3   2   0   8   0   0
0   0   3   0   0   7   0   9   0
0   4   5   1   0   0   0   0   0
2   7   8   0   0   0   9   1   6
0   0   0   0   0   8   4   2   0
0   3   0   6   0   0   2   0   0
0   0   1   0   9   3   6   0   7
0   0   2   7   8   5   0   0   0

Comment: What does the output you are currently printing look like? Is it just missing the vertical lines?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know exactly how to explain the output I need, I don't actually  want this much spaces. I just need to separate the 3x3 blocks with | and - .

Comment: Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/474480/2815227

Comment: @Matthew  it's missing both lines.

Comment: Hint: start by using meaningful variable names. a, n, values ... tell the human reader nothing. Why not row, column, ... and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only missing the vertical lines in each row, you can add a conditional print statement in the line, so after the second and sixth element you add a vertical line.
Maybe something like the following:

```
if(rowIndex == 2 || rowIndex == 5) {
    System.out.print("|");
}
```

edit: one thing to mention with this is that you will need to change your loops to keep track of which index you are at.

Try the following:

```
for(int[]row:values)
    {
        for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < row.length(); rowIndex++)
        {
            System.out.print(row[rowIndex]);
            System.out.print("\t");

            if(rowIndex == 2 || rowIndex == 5) {
                 System.out.print("|");
                 System.out.print("\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 in anticipation of you adding how to add the horizontal lines in the same way (choose whatever looks best from a hyphen, endash, emdash).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void show()
{ 
    for(int x = 0 ; x < 9 ; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0 ; y < 9 ; y++)
        {
            System.out.print(values[x][y]);
            System.out.print("\t");
            if ((y + 1) % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.print("|\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        if ((x + 1) % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.println("----------------------");
        }
    }
}
```